# VBA:highlighting cells that were not found by my search

Tags: vba, excel

```
' On Error Resume Next 'Turn off error handling
            Set mf = Selection.Find(What:=FindText, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False) 'search and find my opnumber
        On Error GoTo 0 'turn back on default error handeling

        If mf Is Nothing Then
        MyActiveSheet.Activate
         With mf
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End With
            GoTo skipit
        Else
            mf.Activate
        End If
```

I am trying to highlight all the cells that weren't found by my search a yellow color. For some reason i cant seem to get it working.

Comment: `I am trying to highlight all the cells` - all cells in entire sheet or all cells in current selection?

Comment: `If mf Is Nothing Then` should be `If Not mf Is Nothing Then`

Comment: highlight the ones that werent found by the search in the selection

Comment: please please get rid of the `GoTo skipit` ;). For using a Range.Find loop I suggest an iterative loop e.g. `Do While Not foundCell Is Nothing: Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(blah blah, after:=foundCell): do more stuff: Loop` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Highlight the ones that werent found by the search *in the selection*

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim mf As Range
    Dim sAddr As String       
    Dim FindText As String

    FindText = "test"

    With Selection
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        Set mf = .Find(What:=FindText, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not mf Is Nothing Then
            sAddr = mf.Address
            Do
                mf.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                Set mf = .FindNext(mf)
                If mf Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While mf.Address <> sAddr
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The main idea is to highlight entire selection with yellow, and then remove highlighting from all cells where `FindText` is found.